# On Azure VM my processes are closed

Tags: windows-server-2008, azure

I'm running a computing task on Microsoft Azure VM. This is a Windows 2008 Server Machine and I use Remote Desktop to connect with.
Anyway, after large amount of time when I'm trying to log in, I see my tasks interrupted and my session seems to be newly created. VM is running all the time (according to account monitor), so I lose my money.
I'm not in servers, I didn't change any settings and I don't understand this behavior.
I tried to run my tasks twice. For the first time my program (and Resource Monitor) was closed after 30h (about 5:00 AM UTC) and for second time after 12h (about 6 AM UTC). Each time I was successfully logging couple of times to check a progress. 
I think Task Scheduler is clear. 
This is a setting issue or someone is killing my app?
Thanks in advance

Comment: there's a timeout for idle/disconnected sessions of rdp and they close automatically. If you are executing tasks in the user session you will always lose what you were doing.

Comment: @BrunoFaria ok, then how to run task in non-user session? Should I "run as administrator" or login as Administrator?

Comment: Thanks to @Bruno I think I found the solution. I have to configure a timeout for RD Session: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754272.aspx

Comment: If you are using windows task scheduler, there's an option that you can set whether the task will be executed even if the user is not logged in. :)